# jQuery Masonry items order

Tags: jquery, layout, jquery-masonry, masonry

I have created the following CodePen: https://codepen.io/cil_dev/pen/rPgNRw

I use the Masonry grid for my website and I encounter a problem with the item number 12 which could be placed after the item number 11.
I don't know where the problem comes from.

This is my code :

```js
$('#grid').masonry({
  columnWidth: '.grid-sizer',
  itemSelector: '.grid-item',
  gutter: 5
});
```

```css
.grid-item {
  float: left;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.grid-sizer,
.grid-item {
 width: calc(88vw / 3 / 2 - 5px);
}

.grid-item.landscape {
  width: calc(88vw / 3 - 5px);
  height: calc(88vw / 3 / 2 - 5px);
  background-color: yellow;
}

.grid-item.portrait {
  width: calc(88vw / 3 / 2 - 5px);
  height: calc(88vw / 3 - 5px);
  background-color: red;
}

.grid-item.square { 
   width: calc(88vw / 3 / 2 - 5px);
   height: calc(88vw / 3 / 2 - 5px);
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="grid">
  <div class="grid-sizer"> </div>

  <div class="grid-item landscape">
    <p>Block 1</p>
  </div>

  <div class="grid-item portrait">
    <p>Block 2</p>
  </div>

  <div class="grid-item square">
    <p>Block 3</p>
  </div>

  <div class="grid-item landscape">
    <p>Block 4</p>
  </div>

  <div class="grid-item landscape">
    <p>Block 5</p>
  </div>

  <div class="grid-item square">
    <p>Block 6</p>
  </div>

  <div class="grid-item landscape">
    <p>Block 7</p>
  </div>

  <div class="grid-item square">
    <p>Block 8</p>
  </div>

  <div class="grid-item portrait">
    <p>Block 9</p>
  </div>

  <div class="grid-item landscape">
    <p>Block 10</p>
  </div>

  <div class="grid-item square">
    <p>Block 11</p>
  </div>

  <div class="grid-item square">
    <p>Block 12</p>
  </div>

  <div class="grid-item square">
    <p>Block 13</p>
  </div>

  <div class="grid-item square">
    <p>Block 14</p>
  </div>

  <div class="grid-item landscape">
    <p>Block 15</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Any ideas on how to fix this?
Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Just add  `horizontalOrder: true` option while you call masonry function.

```
$('#grid').masonry({
  columnWidth: '.grid-sizer',
  itemSelector: '.grid-item',
  gutter: 5,
  horizontalOrder: true,
});
```

You can check more options [here.](https://masonry.desandro.com/options.html)

Comment: Thank you for your answer jigar halani ! I appreciate very much your help. I tried to add this option but unfortunately it doesn't work :(  With "horizontalOrder", every items move

Comment: @Cil horizontalOrder: true should work as per doc may be you need to check css